# <form> HTML tag breaks navigation bar on Google Chrome ONLY

Tags: html, css, forms, google-chrome

As per the title, I used the HTML  tag to create a contact form for my website. When I use the form tag, my navigation bar loses it's position on Google Chrome ONLY.

I have a photo of the Firefox v Chrome layout on the contact page.

[image: Photo]

Top one is Chrome. Bottom is FF.

As you can see the navigation bar is moved on Chrome, although the code IS THE SAME!!

Here is part of the HTML/CSS code for this page.

```
<header class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <a href="index.html">
                <div id="logo">
                    <h1 id="l1">l1</h1>
                    <h1 id="l2">l2</h1>
                    <h2 id="l3">l3</h2>
                    <h3 id="l4">l4</h3>
                </div>
            </a>

            <div id="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="pprojects.html">Personal Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a href="resume.html">Résumé</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div class="subheader">
        <h2>
            Contact
        </h2>
    </div>

    <div class="middle">

        <div class="main-text">
            <p id ="required">
                * Denotes required field.
            </p>

            <form id="con-form" method="post" action="contactsheet.php">
                <label>Name*</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="">

                <label>Email*</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="">

                <label>Subject</label>
                <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="">

                <label>Message</label>
                <textarea name="message" cols="40" rows="5" placeholder="" id="last-box"></textarea>

                <label>What is 2+2? (Anti-spam)*</label>
                <input type="text" name="human" placeholder="">

                <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.header {
    background-color: #283F51;
    height:176px;
    width:100%;
    min-width: 1229px;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    border-style:none;
}

.header .container {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:1214px;
    position:relative;
    padding-top:50px;
    padding-left:15px;
}

.header .container #menu {
    display: inline;
    float:right;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding:0;
    margin-top:70px;
}

/*Further down*/

.middle {
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
    width:1214px;
    overflow:auto;
    padding-left:15px;
    padding-bottom:35px;
    background-color:white;
}

.middle .main-text {
    width:750px;
    float:left;
    margin: 15px 0 0 20px;
    font-family:Lato, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
    color:#424242;
}
```

The code should be right, since it works on FF but not Chrome. I tried to remove the float on the nav bar and move it using position, but it won't align well on FF then :( If anybody can help we I would apreciate it a lot.

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you posted enough code to replicate your problem. As it is, it's entirely unreproducible. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZbYdNw

Comment: It will work on codepen. It doesn't work on Chrome only. I just need someone who had this problem before to tell me how he solved it :/